# i want create shell script file

Tags: command-line, 20.04, scripts, dash-shell

I want create shell script file

in first line i want take PID for process by this command `netstat -nlp | grep :3306`

in second command i want kill process by `kill $(PID)`
but i am find this error when run script

```
 `./docker.sh: line 2: PID: command not found
```

how i can take PID from first command and give to second command
`
this is my file

```
netstat -nlp | grep :3306
kill $(PID)
docker start $(docker ps -a -q)
```

Comment: Always paste your script into `https://shellcheck.net`, a syntax checker, or install `shellcheck` locally. Make using `shellcheck` part of your development process.

Comment: tip: pid from name.. here traverses muli-pids if needed while true; do for i in $(echo $(pidof firefox)); do echo golly "$i"; renice -n 20 "$i"; done; sleep 1 ; done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about passing the output to awk and using a system call to do the job, here is an example which echos the second argument.

ps -ef | grep python | grep grep | awk '{system("echo kill " $2)}'
(This one would kill itself)

You could run your netstat command echoing the argument until you find the correct value eg  $1, $2 ....  Then remove the echo and it will kill your process

netstat -nlp | grep :3306 | awk '{system("echo kill " $1)}'

probably the command you are looking for is
sudo netstat -nlp | grep :3306 | awk  '{print $NF}' | awk -F "/" '{system("kill " $1)}'